# How can I write str_detect more efficiently?

Tags: r

I'm trying to extract specified characters from one column, along with a corresponding row name in my dataframe. Each matched character and name needs to be put into its own dataframe so I can then use the data in an upset plot to show how much overlap there is between characters.

I have some working code but the problem is that its very, very long and clunky. I want to compact the code, I thought perhaps a for loop could work? or maybe case when?

Hopefully someone can help!

Dummy data:

```
name <- rep(1:100, c("rs123", "rs124", "rs125", "rs126", "rs127", "rs128", "rs129", "rs130"))
Source <- rep(1:100, c("dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP"))
chromosome <- rep(1:100, c("17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17"))
evidence <- rep(1:100, c("TOPMed", "Frequency", "Cited", "Frequncy, Cited", "Disease", "ESP", "TOPMed", "GWAS", "1000Genome"))

Biomart <- data.frame(name, source, chromosome, evidence)
```

Current code:

```
'1000Genome' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$evidence,"1000Genomes"),]$name 

'freq' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$evidence,"Frequency"),]$name

'TOPMed' <-  Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$evidence,"TOPMed"),]$name

'gnomAD' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$evidence, "gnomAD"),]$name

'Cited' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$evidence, "Cited"),]$name

'ESP' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$evidence, "ESP"),]$name

'ExAC' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$evidence, "ExAC"),]$name

'Phenotype_or_Disease' <- Biomart[str_detect(Biomart$Variant.supporting.evidence, "Phenotype_or_Disease"),]$Variant.name
```

Comment: Your example data creation code doesn't work. Care to revise it?

Comment: When I do stuff like this in a hurry, I find it convenient to (ab)use the ability of regexes to represent conditional expressions.  So I'd do `df %>% mutate(my_new_column = evidence %>%  str_extract("1000Genome|freq|TOPMed|gnomad|Cited|ESP|ExAC|Phenotype_or_Disease)`.  From there, I can use the new column to index into other things I might care about.  Thus there is only one instance of the `str_extract` code and less repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the code by putting the search strings in a vector, then `sapply` the matching function `str_detect`. This creates a logical matrix. Finally, use the matrix to get the strings you want.

I have left the matched strings like `apply` returns them, in a named list, to leave them in a list is better than to have many vectors in the `.GlobalEnv`. The matched strings vectors will in general not be of the same length, so it will not be possible to form a data.frame, not without further processing.

```r
name <- rep(c("rs123", "rs124", "rs125", "rs126", "rs127", "rs128", "rs129", "rs130"), 100)[1:100]
source <- rep(c("dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP", "dbSNP"), 100)[1:100]
chromosome <- rep(c("17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17", "17"), 100)[1:100]
evidence <- rep(c("TOPMed", "Frequency", "Cited", "Frequency, Cited", "Disease", "ESP", "TOPMed", "GWAS", "1000Genome"), 100)[1:100]

Biomart <- data.frame(name, source, chromosome, evidence)

srch <- c("1000Genome", "Frequency", "TOPMed", "gnomAD", "Cited", "ESP", "ExAC")

inx <- sapply(srch, \(x) stringr::str_detect(Biomart$evidence, x))
apply(inx, 2, \(i) Biomart$name[i])
#> $`1000Genome`
#>  [1] "rs123" "rs124" "rs125" "rs126" "rs127" "rs128" "rs129" "rs130" "rs123"
#> [10] "rs124" "rs125"
#> 
#> $Frequency
#>  [1] "rs124" "rs126" "rs125" "rs127" "rs126" "rs128" "rs127" "rs129" "rs128"
#> [10] "rs130" "rs129" "rs123" "rs130" "rs124" "rs123" "rs125" "rs124" "rs126"
#> [19] "rs125" "rs127" "rs126" "rs128"
#> 
#> $TOPMed
#>  [1] "rs123" "rs129" "rs124" "rs130" "rs125" "rs123" "rs126" "rs124" "rs127"
#> [10] "rs125" "rs128" "rs126" "rs129" "rs127" "rs130" "rs128" "rs123" "rs129"
#> [19] "rs124" "rs130" "rs125" "rs123" "rs126"
#> 
#> $gnomAD
#> character(0)
#> 
#> $Cited
#>  [1] "rs125" "rs126" "rs126" "rs127" "rs127" "rs128" "rs128" "rs129" "rs129"
#> [10] "rs130" "rs130" "rs123" "rs123" "rs124" "rs124" "rs125" "rs125" "rs126"
#> [19] "rs126" "rs127" "rs127" "rs128"
#> 
#> $ESP
#>  [1] "rs128" "rs129" "rs130" "rs123" "rs124" "rs125" "rs126" "rs127" "rs128"
#> [10] "rs129" "rs130"
#> 
#> $ExAC
#> character(0)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>